# Flutter, Visual studio code project stuck on Analyzing

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have a flutter project I can run with no problems using git terminal and flutter command: `flutter run`
but I have been facing this problem recently when I try to open the same project using visual studio code,

once vs code starts, It tries to analyze the project for dart code errors. the procedure usually takes a relatively short time (a minute or so) but now It takes forever and I don't know why.

I tried to do `flutter clean` on my project, but It did not solve it. also tried `flutter pub get`, still not solving the problem. It is very strange because this is only happening when using visual studio code to open that particular project.

here is a log of `flutter doctor -v` command :

```
C:\Users\Rami>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.15.17, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.15.17 at D:\Flutter\sdk
    • Framework revision 2294d75bfa (4 weeks ago), 2020-03-07 00:28:38 +0900
    • Engine revision 5aff311948
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.12.0 9983424a3c)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Rami\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM A520F   • 192.168.8.80:5555 • android-arm64  • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)
    • Chrome     • chrome            • web-javascript • Google Chrome 80.0.3987.162
    • Web Server • web-server        • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

• No issues found!
```

Your feedback is appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 10):

I solved it like [here](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2865). Enable `dart.previewLsp` in your settings.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and enter `dart.previewLsp`.

Also the problem pops up when I code nested generic types. eg. `Future<Either<X, Y>>`.

I avoid this as much as possible. You just need to copy the type from another line or use a snippet. Or code it from inside out.

**Update**

It seems the problem is fixed in recent versions of [Dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44477). Just update your dart installation. Or avoid empty type declarations in generics. eg, `Future<List<>>`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is too late, but I believe this helps any one stuck with this problem. In my case this is due to a syntax error. I tried commenting most recently edited files and restarted `VSCode` then this annoying analyzing thing stopped.

Comment: Jesus, as the analyzer did not highlight it I did not catch the syntax error, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didn't declare any nested generics and didn't finish the line with your var **name** like mine

##### Analyzing for infinite time.

```
Future<List<>>
```

##### Now we are good

```
Future<List<int>> getMyListOfInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me after upgrading to latest Flutter version (1.20.0). Closing and restarting VSCode fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow these steps. It's work for me

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn Analyzer logs on and see on what file its slow/stuck, sometimes that file has syntax error that is not handled by analyzer properly ([how to turn analyzer logs on](https://dartcode.org/docs/logging/#analyzer)).
First column in logs are your system's milliseconds since epoch.

Also enabling `dart.previewLsp` as mentioned by @loki would help.

Another also, double check that your are not out of memory, the analyzer could be very hungry!

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be cache-related.
You could try removing(do a backup just in case) all visual studio cache-related folders here **~/library/caches**, then restart VS and you should be good to go.

This is the naming convention for VS cache folders.

- com.microsoft.VSCode
- com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt