# Solution - VScode Dart Analyzing stuck on (intellisense/autoComplete)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, intellisense, analyzer

[image: see screenshot]

Hello everyone, I've been dealing with vscode analyzing stuck and intellisense/autocomplete not working for a long time, I will share the solution of this problem as approved answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter, Visual studio code project stuck on Analyzing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60976586/flutter-visual-studio-code-project-stuck-on-analyzing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a macbook user, first I viewed the hidden files in the user/your_username/ folder.

> user/your_username/.dartServer/.analysis-driver

I cleaned the inside of the file and restarted vscode. this worked for me.